# AutoLayout with 2 multiline labels, compression resistance and minimum 1 line label

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I have 2 `UILabels` within a fixed-height cell. Both labels are multiline and I need to compress both labels vertically for the case the text won't fit within the cell. I have set slightly higher priority on the first label, as the text is more important there and I have defined vertical space constraints and different compression resistant priorities.

Both labels now successfully adjusts its height for the cell and the second label truncates tail in case the text is too long, but in case there is too much text in both labels, the first label takes priority and compresses the second label so the text is either cut, or the label disappears. How should I configure the AutoLayout so that at least a single line of the second label is always visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hidden label to accomplish this and you won't need to change your existing constraints which are almost giving you the desired behavior.

- Create a hidden label limited to 1 line.
- Set the hidden label's vertical compression resistance to 1000 (required).
- Create an equal heights constraint between the labels you want to require to have at least one line and the new hidden label.
- Set the equal heights constraint to greater than or equal and required (1000) priority.